# Can't get if-else statement to work while detecting screen resolution

Tags: php, if-statement, resolution

I'm making a separate navigation bar on my site for handheld devices, so I've come up with a PHP script that detects the resolution and should output different navigation bars accordingly.

I'm really not that good with php yet, and it took me a while to come up with this rather simple script:

```
<?php if ($(window).width() < 764) : ?>
<p>mobile navigation</p>
<?php else : ?> 
<p>normal navigation</p>    
<?php endif; ?>
```

When I use this, the page does not load anything within or beneath this code, neither the rest of the page. I'd be very grateful if someone could help.

Thanks!

Comment: You realise that php is trying to run this `if`/`else` with the client-side jQuery(?) on the server, before rendering the page to the client?

Comment: You're mixing query and php

Comment: It seems that I have mixed it terribly up. How could I rewrite it to make it work as I desire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

```
<style>
#mobileNavigation {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #mobileNavigation {
    display: block;
  }
  #desktopNavigation {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>

<div id="mobileNavigation">Mobile users see this</div>
<div id="desktopNavigation">Desktop users see this</div>
```

Now, that will need a little more thinking and designing, because you'll then want your entire site to be mobile friendly and [responsive](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/).